# Can I put multiple exception classes in a single java-file and call them as needed?

Tags: custom-exceptions

Please see my custom exception file (ExceptionHandler.java) below:

```
package utilities;


public class ExceptionHandler {
    public void browserException() throws BrowserException {
        new BrowserException();
    }
    public void userInputException() throws UserInputException {
        new UserInputException();
    }
    public void timeOutException() throws TimeOutException {
        new TimeOutException();
    }
    public void notFoundException() throws NotFoundException {
    new NotFoundException();
    }
}

//////////////////// Exception List Here ////////////////////
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class BrowserException extends Exception {
    public BrowserException() {
        System.out.println("Unhandled Browser!");
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class UserInputException extends Exception {
    public UserInputException() {
        System.out.println("Invalid user-input!");
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class TimeOutException extends Exception {
    public TimeOutException() {
        System.out.println("Script timed out!");
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class NotFoundException extends Exception {
    public NotFoundException() {
        System.out.println("Element Not Found!");
    }
}
```

I'm trying to call this ExceptionHandler-class as shown-below, but getting errors like "No exception of type void can be thrown; an exception type must be a subclass of Throwable".

```
throw new ExceptionHandler().browserException();
```

Kindly anyone let me know, if at all it is a valid way. If not, then what all could be the best possible approaches to group multiple custom-exception classes? Please bear with me as I'm a novice in Exception Handling.

Many thanks!

Comment: You should return the `new BrowserException` instead of throw in the method `browserException()` for your usage. Or throw the exception in the method and change to `new ExceptionHandler().browserException()` without `throw`.

Answer (score 0):

You should call

throw new BrowserException

Comment: Another question. Which import statement should I use in this case?...
(a)    import utilities.ExceptionHandler; OR
(b)    import utilities.BrowserException;

Please note- "ExceptionHandler" is the public class and "BrowserException" is non-public class.

Comment: Also is there anymore need of keeping the methods- browserException(), userInputException(), timeOutException(), notFoundException() inside the ExceptionHandler-class??? I do not find them having value anymore.

Comment: You can remove the methods it is useless. Your ide helps you to organize imports